# PHP Application logs out within seconds

Tags: php, session

I have a PHP/MySQL application which processes a lot of data. When I use session regeneration, my application logs the user out over and over again within a matter of seconds.

To resolve this, I disabled the session regeneration. I have set `gc maxlifetime = 86400`.

Could it be possible that a memory leak or long execution time of some heavy PHP script/loop which is not coded properly be at the source of this problem?

```
function checklogin()
{
  if ( isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && ( time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 86400 ) )
     {
        session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time
        session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage              
     }
}

function login()  
{ 
   session_start(); 
   //  session_regenerate_id();  //ON USING IT LOGSOUT, SO I STOPPED USING THIS
   $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
}
```

I need to use the session regeneration but it shouldn't log out.

Comment: So, what is your question? Please, take the [tour]. **Edit:** As a 3K+ rep user, you should know better than to ask a question like this.

Comment: @Script47 : I need to use the session regeneration but it shouldn't log out . Kindly help with code.

Comment: I would consider moving the session start out of the function and making sure every script runs it just after the first `<?php` If you have output anything in the main body of your script, before calling this function, a `session_start()` wont actually work. In these situation though it will report an error in the php error log are you getting any errors in there like `Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent`

Comment: @RiggsFolly : I am calling the login function at the top of every script, as you 
   have mentioned, thus am not getting any header errors.

Answer (score 0):

session_start() must be the first instruction execute ever if you want work with cookies.

Comment: '*if you want work with cookies*' - The function name implies otherwise, no?

Comment: @Xtoxico : Does session regeneration uses cookies ?